# ftpClient.retrieveFileStream returns null reply code 550, Failed to Open File

Tags: java, ftp-client

I'm working on Commons net FTPClient 2.0 Api but `ftpClient.retrieveFileStream()` returns `null`

> Job DEFAULT.Snapshot Data Loader threw an unhandled Exception: 
>   (2014-01-07 23:45:15,317
>   QuartzScheduler_Worker-1_org.quartz.core.JobRunShell)
>   net.unicon.sakora.impl.exception.SakoraRuntimeException: Retrieving of
>   file sakai/READGROUPSMGMT2014-01-08T07.37.41.000000Z.xml failed. 550.
>   Failed to Open File..

I tried to use `ByteArrayOutputStream()` and `retrieveFile()` instead of `retrieveFileStream()` and it throws:

> Java.io.EOFException java.io.EOFException: input contained no data
>   at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.fillBuf(MXParser.java:3003)

Any help will be appreciated.
Regards,